# Show that $\int_0^2 \int_0^2 \frac{x}{1+\ln(x^2y^2)} \,\mathrm{d}x \,\mathrm{d}y \leq 4$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, upper-lower-bounds

> Show that
>   $$
>   \int_0^2 \int_0^2 \frac{x}{1+\ln(x^2y^2)} \,\mathrm{d}x \,\mathrm{d}y \leq 4.
> $$

When I think somewhat outside the box, I can see that when I sketch the boundaries in a one-dimensional way, it is clearly a square area with a side length of $2$, and obviously $2^2 = 4$. So in theory, if the definite integral is finding the area in certain contraints, the area has to be $\leq 4$

Is this the correct approach to this kind of question? And if so where should I go next?

This is only worth $2$ of $25$ marks which would indicate to me that I am not expected to actually complete the integration.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: show that the integrand is bounded above by $1$ in that square.

Comment: @SeanRoberson The integrand is *not* bounded above by $1$ in that square. Take for example $x=1.1,y=0.9$.

Comment: The integral obviously diverges when the denominator runs into 0.

Comment: OP: Can you double check this question for correctness? As mentioned above, the integrand diverges when $1 + \ln \left(x^2y^2\right) = 0$.

Comment: @WinterSoldier: I believe there is nothing wrong here. The integrand function has singularities, but they are integrable singularities. Better to split the integration range in four equal squares and to perform tight estimations over each piece.

Comment: @WinterSoldier no this is the correct question.  Apologies I was asleep as it was midnight in my timezone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

About *thinking outside the box*: one of the main tricks in Math is to exploit the exchange of sums/limits/integrals. This trick has many forms: double counting, Feynman's trick, Wilf-Zeilberger couples, Fubini's theorem, creative telescoping... they all boil down to the same powerful idea. In our case we may try to write $\frac{1}{1+2\log(xy)}$ as $\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-t} x^{-2t} y^{-2t}\,dt $ to get...

$$ \iint_{(1,2)^2}\frac{x}{1+2\log(xy)}\,dx\,dy = \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-t}\iint_{(1,2)^2} x^{1-2t} y^{-2t}\,dx\,dy\,dt $$
(the situation gets temporarily worse) then
$$ \iint_{(1,2)^2}\frac{x}{1+2\log(xy)}\,dx\,dy = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{(4^t-2)(4^t-4)}{(2t-2)(2t-1)} 4^{-2t} e^{-t}\,dt $$
(which is much better, since we have an integral in a single variable). Despite its algebraic nastyness the function $\frac{(4^t-2)(4^t-4)}{(2t-2)(2t-1)} 4^{-2t}$ has a very simple behaviour on $\mathbb{R}^+$: it is positive, decreasing and bounded above by $\frac{3}{2}\,\exp\left(-\frac{7}{5}t\right)$. In particular the original integral over $(1,2)^2$ does not exceed $\frac{5}{8}$. I leave to you to adapt this approach for dealing with the contribution over $(0,1)\times(1,2)$, $(1,2)\times(0,1)$ and $(0,1)^2$.

$4$ is actually a very loose upper bound for the original integral: a sharper bound is $I\leq \frac{17}{14}$.

Comment: Don't you have to worry at some point about the improper nature of the integral at the points where $1+2\log(xy)=0$?

Comment: This seems mathematically sound! However very advanced for the level mathematics my class is at currently. I will ask in class today if I can set some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so for anyone interested in the required answer, I've been told that for my level of mathematics, we can simply state: because $\int_0^2\int_0^2xdxdy=4$, and as $x$ divided by anything greater than one, as stipulated in the inequality, will always be $\le{x}$, the double integral will be$\int_0^2\int_0^2{x\over1+log(1 + x^2y^2)}dxdy\le4$

Comment: Huh? How is $1+\ln(x^2y^2)$ always greater than $1$??! You sure the question wasn't about $1+(\ln(xy))^2$, because then your answer makes perfectly sense. Look how just one misplaced bracket makes so much difference!

Comment: I'm so sorry you're right. The bracket wasn't misplace but it was ln(1+x ^2y^2)